# Use #define to replace code

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c

There is a chuck of code in my iOS application which I have to use in every view - can't have it in a function/methods - so I was wondering if there is any way I can use #define and use it's identifier where it is required. Below is sample code.

The Code Which I would like to replace with #deinfe identifer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification) 
                                             name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorLeft 
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification) 
                                             name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorRight 
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewTopDidResetNotification)
                                             name:ECSlidingViewTopDidReset 
                                           object:nil];
```

So I was wondering how I can can #define it and use it within ViewDidLoad Method?

Comment: do you want all three in one #define or three different #define?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - All in one.

Comment: Why can't you have it in a function or methods?

Comment: @Simon - Good question. It's not like I can't define the function but the same function will be repeated in each file - which kind of sucks - and then there are corresponding methods to handle these notifications. Just want to reduce the max code.

Comment: couldn't you put the function where the #define is? As I understand it, #defines are sometimes a bit tricky so I would recommend a function instead (although, it was a long time ago since I used C++).

Comment: @itsaboutcode why would it need to be repeated in each file?  You could define it as NS_INLINE in its own header file and just #import that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

Put \ after a space at the end of each line, this prevents the compiler to check for new line or enter key pressed. *This makes the code readable.* Then you can use MY_NOTIFICATIONS any where in your method.

```
#define MY_NOTIFICATIONS [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self \
selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification) \
name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorLeft \
object:nil]; \
\
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self \
                                         selector:@selector (_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification) \
                                             name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorRight \
                                           object:nil]; \
\
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self \
                                         selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewTopDidResetNotification) \
                                             name:ECSlidingViewTopDidReset \
                                           object:nil]; \
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your questions, but as an old C++ programmer who has dealt with the many headaches of the preprocessor, I would advise against using a #define for this.

A couple options...

1. Define a base class (derived from UIViewController) with your two selectors. The selectors can be overridden in your derived classes.

   @interface YourBaseCass : UIViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad; // Put your add observer logic here
   - (void)_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification;
   - (void)_gotECSlidingViewTopDidResetNotification;

   @end

   @implementation YourBaseCass

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad //make sure you call me from the derived class
   {
       [super viewDidLoad]
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification)
                                                    name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorLeft
                                                  object:nil];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification)
                                                    name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorRight
                                                  object:nil];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewTopDidResetNotification)
                                                    name:ECSlidingViewTopDidReset
                                                  object:nil];
   }
   ```

   @end
2. Put your functionality in a global static method (if subclassing isn't your thing). This will be easier to debug.

   - (void)addObserversForObject:(id)object{
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:object
                                                  selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification)
                                                      name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorLeft
                                                    object:nil];

     ```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:object
                                              selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification)
                                                  name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorRight
                                                object:nil];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:object
                                              selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewTopDidResetNotification)
                                                  name:ECSlidingViewTopDidReset
                                                object:nil];
     ```

     }

Comment: Sorry for the poor code formatting... I can't seem to make the different areas line up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick, provided the code is supposed to be exactly like that. otherwise you could put arguments to the `#define` to change some things about it

```
#define identifier do{ [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification) name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorLeft  object:nil];\
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewAnchorRightOrRightrNotification) name:ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorRight object:nil];\
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_gotECSlidingViewTopDidResetNotification) name:ECSlidingViewTopDidReset object:nil];\
} while (0);
```

Comment: the do while makes sure that it can be used inside single line if statements and such

Comment: (at) Fonix's Comment: Can't you just add curly brackets around the expression to do the same?

Comment: i for some reason remember their being a problem with that, but cant think of it right now. maybe there isnt, but a do while has always worked for me

Comment: Even a { and  } will act as a block, there is no need of either loop or block. you can simply use all in one line as I did in answer.

Comment: you answer is still treated as 3 lines in code, which can break things if you use it in a single line if statement or for loop etc. probably wont be used like that in this case but its good practise. (if you notice i still have to use \'s as well)

Answer (score 0):

Don't lean on the preprocessor.  It's bad style, and often leads to subtle confusions.  And you'll still need to #include the macro in all those files.

Instead, define a class to handle the notifications

```
@interface ECSReceptionist
      - (id) initFor: (id) observer;
@end
```

This might seem a bit lightweight for a class, but you can give it responsibilities later. For example, the Receptionist might also register itself for notifications and handle some routine chores autonomously.

Avoiding the preprocessor:

- makes your intent clearer
- avoids subtle syntactic tsorus, saving sanity
- makes debugging much easier
- provides opportunities for further refactoring
- gives you a test hook for unit testing